# Django template is not showing the maximum value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am having trouble displaying the maximum value on the html template from my mysql database.

my view:
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.db.models import Count, Min, Sum, Avg, Max

```
from .models import Gwtable
import datetime

def index(request):
    maxiumum_value =  Gwtable.objects.all().aggregate(Max('salesprice'))
```

my html

```
<div>
    <p> {{ maxiumum_value.values|floatformat:2 }}</p>
</div>
```

[my shell test to prove the data is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eISPC.png)
Any other potential solutions here?

Comment: what is that `maxiumum_value.values` ? maybe it would be only `maximum_value`

Answer (score 0):

Your shell test shows that you are getting a dictionary. Using `values` on a dictionary gives you a collection of values. So using `floatformat` directly on that makes no sense at all.

Instead of using `values`, you should directly access the value you want by its key:

```
{{ maxiumum_value.salesprice__max|floatformat:2 }}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! made the changes but still no luck. when I try to mimic the action in the shell it tells me 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'salesprice__max'. any thoughts?